# Importing .obo file with OntologyX package in R results in 'attempt to set an attribute on NULL' error

Tags: r, owl, ontology, protege

Problem with importing .obo file with onotolgyX package.

I want to import people.obo with R package ontologyX:

```
library(ontologyIndex)

hp <- get_OBO("people.obo")
```

I have created obo file from this ontology:

https://www.michaeldebellis.com/post/the-people_example-ontology

With this tool:

http://robot.obolibrary.org/convert

I get this result when I want to import it:

```
> hp <- get_OBO("people.obo")
Error in names(object) <- nm : attempt to set an attribute on NULL
```

I get the same problems if I convert owl to obo with protege or if I use Pizza ontology:

https://www.michaeldebellis.com/post/new-protege-pizza-tutorial

It doesn't work.

But everythnig works fine when I try to open go-basic.obo

http://geneontology.org/docs/download-ontology/

Any help ?

Answer (score 1):

The answer from the author of the package ;)

*'name' properties were not assigned to terms in the obo file - which should be allowed - so I have updated the package (see version 2.11) so that it uses the 'id' if the name is absent (should be on CRAN shortly and work on the examples you provided).*